# Axios Post Request From LocalHost Giving 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, http-status-code-404, axios

My first time using Axios and Im struggling to get a response in my React-Redux app:

The request is:

```
export default function signUp(username, password) {
  let settings = {
      url: "https://api.example.com/signup",
      data: {
        "Username" : username,
        "Password" : password },
      method: 'POST',
      headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      transformRequest: [(data) => {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      }]
  };
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    dispatch( signUpRequest());
    console.log( "%c settings are...", "color : white", settings );
    axios( settings ).then(
      ( response ) => {
        console.log( "%c and the response is...", "color : blue", response );
      }
    ).catch(
      ( response ) => {
        console.log( "%c and the error is...", "color : pink", response );
      }
    );
  };
}
```

I am getting an error of 404 - Not Found. The `url` (edited for privacy) should be correct above. Is there anything else I am doing wrong? Could it be an issue with localhost? How can I check / test?

Edit: Previous header mentioned was incorrect. Im getting the following:

[image]

Comment: According to the screenshot, you're actually getting 400 Bad Request (not 404, like you describe), which means that the server rejects for a reason.